# Not performing matrix operations while using switch case in JAVA program

Tags: java, class

I am having a run time error in my following JAVA code , This program is to add , multiply, and to find the transpose of two matrices by taking input by the user. But it is not giving appropriate output

```
import java.util.*;

class Matrixoperation {

static Scanner s1=new Scanner(System.in);

static int a[][],b[][],c[][],rows_a,cols_a,rows_b,cols_b,rows_c,cols_c;

static void get() {

    System.out.println("enter the number of rows and cols for both the matrices that are to added");

    rows_a=s1.nextInt();

    cols_a=s1.nextInt();

    rows_b=s1.nextInt();

    cols_b=s1.nextInt();

    a=new int[rows_a][cols_a];

    b=new int[rows_b][cols_b];

    System.out.println("enter values for first matrix");

    for(int i=0;i<rows_a;i++) {

        for(int j=0;j<cols_a;j++)

        {

            a[i][j]=s1.nextInt();

        }

    }

    System.out.println("enter values for second matrix");

    for(int i=0;i<rows_b;i++) {

        for(int j=0;j<cols_b;j++)

        {

            b[i][j]=s1.nextInt();

        }

    }

}

static void display() {

    for(int i=0;i<rows_c;i++) {

        for(int j=0;j<cols_c;j++) {

            System.out.print(c[i][j]+"\t");

        }

        System.out.println("\n");

    }

}

static void add() {

    

if(rows_a==rows_b && cols_a==cols_b) {

    rows_c=rows_a;

    cols_c=cols_b;

    c=new int[rows_c][cols_c];

    for(int i=0;i<rows_a;i++) {

        for(int j=0;j<cols_b;j++) {

            c[i][j]=a[i][j]+b[i][j];

        }

    }

}

}

static void multiply() {

    if(cols_a==rows_b) {

        rows_c=rows_a;

        cols_c=cols_b;

        c=new int[rows_c][cols_c];

        for(int i=0;i<rows_a;i++) {

            for(int j=0;j<cols_b;j++) {

                c[i][j]=0;

                for(int k=0;k<cols_a;k++) {

                    c[i][j]+=a[i][k]*b[k][j];

                }

            }

        }

    }

    

    

}

static void transpose() {
int transpose_matrix[][]=new int[rows_a][cols_a];
int transpose_matrix_1[][]=new int[rows_b][cols_b];
for(int i=0;i<rows_a;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<cols_a;j++)
    {
        transpose_matrix[cols_a][rows_a]=a[rows_a][cols_a];
    }
}
    System.out.println("The transpose of first matrix is:-");
    for(int i=0;i<cols_a;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<rows_a;j++)
        {
           System.out.println(transpose_matrix_1[rows_a][cols_a]+" ");      
          System.out.println("\n");
        }
            
     }
//transpose of  second matrix
    
    for(int i=0;i<rows_b;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<cols_b;j++)
        {
            transpose_matrix_1[cols_b][rows_b]=b[rows_b][cols_b];
        }
    }
        System.out.println("The transpose of first matrix is:-");
        for(int i=0;i<cols_a;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<rows_a;j++)
            {
               System.out.println(transpose_matrix_1[rows_a][cols_a]+" ");      
              System.out.println("\n");
            }
                
         }
    s1.close();

}
    

    
    



public static void main(String ar[]) {

    Matrixoperation m1=new Matrixoperation();

    int ch; 

  

//    m1.get();

    while(true) {

    System.out.println("Enter which option to perform"+"\n1.Get the matrix"+"\n 2.Add two matrices"+"\n3. Multiply two matrices"+"\n 4.Transpose of matrices"+"\n5.Display");

    ch=s1.nextInt();

    switch(ch)

    {

        case 1:m1.get();

            break;

        

        case 2:m1.add();

            break;

        

        case 3:m1.multiply();

            break;

        

        case 4:m1.transpose();

            break;

        

        case 5:m1.display();

            break;

       }

    System.out.println("want to continue y for yes and n for no");

    char c=s1.next().charAt(0);

    if(c=='n')break;

    }



}

}
```

I performed this on eclipse and it does not show sum , multiplication, and transpose in output. Sometimes it is just taking user input but not performing matrix operations. Please help me with this code.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: please add the stack trace

Comment: Was all of this code absolutely necessary to demonstrate your problem? Could you have made a subset of the code which demonstrated it? Please read about [mre].

Comment: Please format your code properly. Remove those empty lines and fix your indentation.